# Suggestions for html tag info required for jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have [written a tiny bit](https://github.com/tobya/jqtfm/blob/master/src/jqSelectOption.js) of jQuery which simply selects all the `Select` form elements on the page and sets the selected property to the correct value.  Previously I had to write code to generate the `Select` in php and specify the `Selected` attribute for the option that was selected or do loads of `if` statements in my php page or smarty template.

Obviosly the information about what option is selected still needs to be specified somewhere in the page so the jQuery code can select it.

I decided to create a new attribute on the Select item

```
<Select name="MySelect" SelectedOption="2">  <-- Custom Attr SelectedOption
<option value="1">My Option 1 </option>
<option value="2">My Option 2 </option> <-- this option will be selected when jquery code runs
<option value="3">My Option 3 </option>
<option value="4">My Option 4 </option>
</Select>
```

Does anyone see a problem with using a custom attribute to do this, is there a more accepted way, or a better jquery way?

Comment: Having done many "clever" tricks like this, I feel the need to tell you that the best thing to do is start over and refactor whatever you have to to get the HTML to work as intended. That is, "selected='selected'" on the OPTION tags. By using this custom attribute, you are forcing any future code change to go through that same pathway to interact with these dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure you want this, you should call it `data-something`.

> A new feature being introduced in HTML 5 is the addition of custom data attributes. This is a, seemingly, bizarre addition to the specification - but actually provides a number of useful benefits.
>
> Simply, the specification for custom data attributes states that any
>   attribute that starts with "data-" will be treated as a storage area
>   for private data (private in the sense that the end user can't see it
>   - it doesn't affect layout or presentation).

This is because, otherwise, the HTML you produce is invalid by HTML5 and will fail such validation checks.

This has very little to do with jQuery - jQuery is more about DOM *manipulation*, what you're really asking is a HTML question which can really only be answered by considering the standards (HTML5 or otherwise). That said, for readability, you *should* have the value inside the HTML. Anywhere else would just be confusing and unmaintainable in the long run.

Source: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ (which points to http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/#custom)

Comment: What would I do if I wasn't 'absolutely sure' I wanted to do this?

Comment: Start from the beginning, and ask yourself why you want this plugin. Many PHP frameworks (CakePHP, CodeIgniter) offer full HTML-form suites which will generate <selects> *and* have the correct one selected (either automagically based on the form post, or something you supply, or a default) without writing a single line of HTML.

Comment: Because I have a legacy application that doesn't use a framework :)  I'll change my attribute to `data-SelectedOption`